# How to have source instead of html in WebView in React Native

Tags: webview, react-native

Recently, React Native has deprecated `html` and `url` props and replaced them with `source`.

```
<WebView
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
    contentInset={{top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0}}
    html={"<style>*{margin:0;padding:0;}canvas{position:absolute;transform:translateZ(0);}</style><canvas></canvas><script>var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');(" + renderString + ").call(" + contextString + ", canvas);</script>"}
    opaque={false}
    underlayColor={'transparent'}
    style={this.props.style}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
/>
```

How to replace the `html` with `source`. Just replacing doesn't do the trick. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
<WebView source={{ html: "<h1>Hello</h1>" }} />
```

Documentation available here: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#content

Comment: Just wanted to mention that in recent version of React Native you should also add the "originWhitelist" property in order for html source to work properly... like so: <WebView source={{ html: "<h1>Hello</h1>" }} originWhitelist={['*']} />

Answer (score 1):

Have you upgraded React Native version? 
It is deprecated on newer versions, check the documentation. If you are using older version of React Native, you should use `html` instead of `source`.