# Web View Not loading in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have this following Html that i am trying to load to a web view but it is not loading in Snack only white screen + no error

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import Component from './ReactComp';

export default class App extends React.Component {


  initialHTMLContent = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/rahulrsingh09-stenciltest2@0.0.3/dist/test/test.js'></script>
  
</head>

<body>
Hello
<my-component source-url="https://fcc3ddae59ed.us-west-2.playback.live-video.net/api/video/v1/us-west-2.893648527354.channel.DmumNckWFTqz.m3u8"></my-component>


</body>

</html>
  `



  render() {
    return (
          <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
      }}
    >
            <WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}    
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
         source={{html: this.initialHTMLContent, baseUrl: null}}
        // source={{uri : 'https://www.twitch.tv/videos/721473497'}}
      />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

https://snack.expo.io/@rahulrsingh09/webview-example. The Html Loads standalone when saved as .html file

Comment: please check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35754498/9055402)

Comment: @PankajMeena I am doing the same thing, please check the snack link for further details